# Pyomo Constraint Declaration Displays Unexpected Calculation?

Tags: python, pyomo

In the following example model, I am attempting to create a constraint function that takes the sum of `model.auction` * `model.volume` for each item in a set, deducts it from parameter `model.icCap` and assigns that value to the variable `model.daVol`:

```
model = ConcreteModel()

model.WEEKS = Set(initialize = [1,2,3])
model.MONTHS = Set(initialize = ['J24','F24'])
model.PRODS = Set(initialize = ['Q24','J24','F24'])

model.icCap = Param(initialize = 900)

model.auction = Var(model.WEEKS,model.PRODS, within = Binary)
model.volume = Var(model.WEEKS,model.PRODS, within = NonNegativeIntegers)
model.daVol = Var(model.MONTHS, within = NonNegativeIntegers)

def daVol_rule(model,j):
     return model.icCap - sum(model.auction[i,j] * model.volume[i,j] for i in model.WEEKS) == model.daVol[j]
model.daVol_const = Constraint(model.MONTHS, rule = daVol_rule)
```

However, upon viewing the created statement for `daVol_const` in `pprint()`, I notice that it appears to be deducting `daVol[j]` at the end of each statement. This, I believe, is causing my objective function to calculate incorrectly.

See below (scroll along to end):

```
1 Constraint Declarations
    daVol_const : Size=2, Index=MONTHS, Active=True
        Key : Lower : Body                                                                                                            : Upper : Active
        F24 :   0.0 : 900 - (auction[1,F24]*volume[1,F24] + auction[2,F24]*volume[2,F24] + auction[3,F24]*volume[3,F24]) - daVol[F24] :   0.0 :   True
        J24 :   0.0 : 900 - (auction[1,J24]*volume[1,J24] + auction[2,J24]*volume[2,J24] + auction[3,J24]*volume[3,J24]) - daVol[J24] :   0.0 :   True
```

Am I misunderstanding the `pprint()` output here or have I incorrectly formatted my constraint function perhaps?

Guidance appreciated!

Comment: You are misunderstanding the printed output. pyomo brings all the variable to a single expression and calculates lower & upper values.
If you assign constraint as "a == b", then pyomo shows the expression as "a-b" and sets lower & upper values as zero which is essentially the same.

Comment: Many thanks @Asettisriharsha, I had a sneaking feeling that may have been the case. Appreciate the confirmation!